# How to find common items across most lists [not all if can't] in C#

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have lists like this

```
List<List<uint>> AllLists = new List<List<uint>>();
List<uint> TestList1 = new List<uint>();
List<uint> TestList2 = new List<uint>();
List<uint> TestList3 = new List<uint>();
TestList1.Add(0x18A);
TestList1.Add(0x188);
TestList1.Add(0x188);
TestList1.Add(0x188);
TestList1.Add(0x188);
TestList1.Add(0x188);
TestList1.Add(0x188);
TestList1.Add(0x670);

TestList2.Add(0x670);
TestList2.Add(0x670);

TestList3.Add(0xBADC0DE); //this one is empty.. but could contain some useless ones (not 0x670).
AllLists.Add(TestList1.ToList());
AllLists.Add(TestList2.ToList());
AllLists.Add(TestList3.ToList());
List<uint> MostCommonOffset = FindCommon(AllLists);
```

> List 1 Has: 0x18A,0x188,0x188,0x188,0x188,0x188,0x188,0x670
>  List 2 Has: 0x670,0x670
>  List 3 is 0xBADC0DE.

It should get the answer `0x670`.. even though the 3rd list doesn't contain it since its the only one that exists in most of the lists.

Theoretically if second or third list contained `0x188` that was be favored as a better answer since there is alot of it in list 1.. and it exists in 2 lists (most lists). But it should still give both answers `0x670` and `0x188`.

If list 2 or list 3 also contained `0x188`, then the answer should have 2 common ones. `0x670` and `0x188`

Here is the function I was using previously but it needs to find a match in all lists.. but that's not always possible.

```
   public static List<T> FindCommon<T>(List<List<T>> lists)
    {
        //This checks to make sure all commons are the same in all lists.
        List<uint> Counts = new List<uint>();
        List<List<T>> Matches = new List<List<T>>();
        bool Found = false;
        //List<T> curCheck;
        foreach (List<T> list in lists)
        {
            Found = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < Counts.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Matches[i].Count == list.Count)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
                    {
                        //they not equals
                        if ((dynamic)Matches[i][j] != (dynamic)list[j])
                            goto next_loop;
                        //fully equal, increase count for repeated match found.
                        if (j == list.Count - 1)
                        {
                            Counts[i]++;
                            Found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                next_loop:
                if (Found) break;
                continue;
            }

            if (!Found)
            {
                Counts.Add(1);
                Matches.Add(list);
            }
        }

        return Matches[Counts.IndexOf(Counts.Max())];
    }
```

Here is a simple one that checks all lists but doesn't check most common across lists not all lists if it can't.

```
public static List<T> FindCommon<T>(params List<T>[] lists)
{
    //This checks to make sure all the commons that are partilly in all lists.

    return lists
        .SelectMany(x => x)
        .Distinct()
        .Where(item => lists.All(l => l.Contains(item)))
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: @ThomasWeller what i do wrong?

Comment: @ThomasWeller what is messy the FindCommon function? the top is a example to compact it into a question I tried to make it as basic as i could, its more complicated in my whole code.

Comment: Why so much downvotes its very hard for me to figure this out.

Comment: It's not clear what your requirements actually are.

Comment: `TestList3.Clear(0xBADC0DE);` makes compile error `No overload for method 'Clear' takes 1 arguments.`

Comment: Sorry I did a bad edit there it was .Add. Sorry

Comment: You missed some semicolons in `AllLists.Add` lines.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Han, your a life savior.

Comment: @SSpoke You're welcome. It's like a brain challenge for me :)

Comment: If you do a distinct on each list, concatenate them, group by the values, and count, wouldn't that give you the number of lists each item occurs in?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes, a distinct method might be more efficient.

Comment: `var most = (lists.Count + 1) / 2;
    return lists.SelectMany(l => l.Distinct()).GroupBy(i => i).Where(g => g.Count() >= most).Select(g => g.Key).ToList();`

Comment: Hey @LasseVågsætherKarlsen whats the `var most = (lists.Count + 1) / 2;` mean

Comment: It is one way of figuring out how many lists "most lists" mean, which is half, rounded up. So of 2 lists, one requires the item, of 3 lists, 2 requires the item. If you mean *more than half*, then `+ 2` would have to be used, or `list.Count / 2 + 1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ solution with some explaination. Also LINQPad tips on debugging.

```
List<List<uint>> AllLists = new List<List<uint>>();
List<uint> TestList1 = new List<uint>();
List<uint> TestList2 = new List<uint>();
List<uint> TestList3 = new List<uint>();
TestList1.Add(0x18A);
TestList1.Add(0x188);
TestList1.Add(0x188);
TestList1.Add(0x188);
TestList1.Add(0x188);
TestList1.Add(0x188);
TestList1.Add(0x188);
TestList1.Add(0x670);

TestList2.Add(0x670);
TestList2.Add(0x670);

TestList3.Add(0xBADC0DE); //this one is empty.. but could contain some useless ones (not 0x670).
AllLists.Add(TestList1.ToList());
AllLists.Add(TestList2.ToList());
AllLists.Add(TestList3.ToList());

var numbers = AllLists
    .Select(x => x
        .GroupBy(y => y)                    // group the numbers in each sub-list
        .Select(z => new { Key = z.Key }))  // select only the key in each sub-list
    .SelectMany(x => x)                     // flatten the lists
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key)                    // group by the keys
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())      // sort the count of keys from largest to smallest
    ;

var mostCount = numbers
    .Select(x => x.Count())                 // select the count of keys only
    .Take(1)                                // take one, actually this line is not needed. you can remove it
    .FirstOrDefault();                      // take the largest count of key (the counts were sorted in previous linq statement)

var numberWithMostCount = numbers
    .Where(x => x.Count() == mostCount)     // filter the largest count of in the lists
    .Select(x => x.Key)                     // select the key only
    ;

foreach (var n in numberWithMostCount)
    Console.WriteLine(n);                   // print all key who has the largest count
```

You might notice that I called some Dump() methods in the LINQ statements in my earlier edits. I wrote and debug the code in LinqPad. It has Dump() method to easily see the result of LINQ operations. Let's say I put a Dump() method in the code (open picture in new tab if it's too small). The Dump() method shows the result of LINQ method's execution. You can put a Dump() method after each Linq methods. Try adding Dump() method in any lines with comments, preferably one or two Dump() at one time.

[image]

Suggestion from [Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v%C3%A5gs%C3%A6ther-karlsen). Use Distinct() to remove duplicates. Thanks, Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen.

```
var numbers = AllLists
    .Select(x => x.Distinct())              // remove duplicates
    .SelectMany(x => x)                     // flatten the lists
    .GroupBy(x => x)                        // group by the keys
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())      // sort the count of keys from largest to smallest
    ;
```

Comment: Wow that was quick haha let me try it out

Comment: @SSpoke I added some explanations.

Comment: doesn't seem to work right for me on a bigger example.. it gets the most common in one list.. not across 3 lists.

Comment: Add a bigger example in your question.

Comment: Okay second, its the same thing but different numbers. I'll add it all.

Comment: I get `0x188` as answer not `0x670`

Comment: @SSpoke 0x188 has 6 duplicates, 0x670 has 3 duplicates. Answer is 0x168, isn't it?

Comment: Nope... you need the count per list not across all lists

Comment: @SSpoke I think I got it now. I misunderstood your requirement.

Comment: @SSpoke Thanks for accepting and upvoting my answer. I can some explaination in the code if you want.

Comment: If you want sure, I can't understand how you figure out mostCount from just the answer alone, but don't need to if you dont want too.

Comment: @SSpoke I added some explaination and a picture. Hope it helps you to understand how the code works.

Comment: Thanks I understand it better now the mostCount is how much lists contain most common value.  LOVE YOU MAN

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179255/discussion-between-han-and-sspoke).